# Android DefaultHTTPClient filling a form by Post request on javascript driven website

Tags: java, javascript, android, httpclient, http-post

My problem is similar to this:
[HTTPclient POST with problematic web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775585/httpclient-post-with-problematic-web-site)

I used tamper data to find all the request going through the client and server.

I initially executed the get request to load the page and get the dynamically generated field values. Then I created the list of named value pairs for all the input fields of the concerned form and executed post req, however it redirects me to an error page.

I tried setting cookie and handling sslfactory in all possible ways suggested on stackoverflow:

- [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)
- [Android HttpClient persistent cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146861/android-httpclient-persistant-cookies)

but it's not working for me.

I don't know what's the problem, I don't even get any error in logs.
I spent a couple of days on this single issue.

Comment: I solved this prob by my own finally. Using HTTPCLeint itself. I was not extracting the hideen field values correctly.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was using the same *HttpClient* without any need of maintaining cookies or anything else.
Firstly find all the request(get or post) those are made using tamper data. Then extract the dynamically generated hidden field values:

```
public static String getPage(String sURL) throws HttpException {
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet(sURL);

    // method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER,
    // new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

    try {
        /*
        * int statusCode = client.execute(method); if (statusCode !=
        * HttpStatus.SC_OK) { System.err.println("Method failed: " +
        * method.getStatusLine()); }
        */HttpResponse res;
        res = client.execute(method);

        BasicResponseHandler myHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String content = myHandler.handleResponse(res);
        //extract dynamic parameters here
        return content;
    } catch(...) {

    }
}
```

Then for post use this method:

```
public static String postPage1(list of parameters to be passed in the post form) throws HttpException {
    BasicNameValuePair[] data = {
        new BasicNameValuePair("field name", "param1"),
        ......
    };
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(sURL);

    // post.setRequestBody(data);
    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Arrays.asList(data)));

        HttpResponse res;
        res = client.execute(post);
        int statusCode;

        BasicResponseHandler myHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String content = myHandler.handleResponse(res);
        return content;
    } catch (...) {

    }
}
```

That's it.